# DeserializeXmlNode is encoding "&"

Tags: c#, json.net

I am calling a REST service that returns json data that contains the ampersand.  I have verified that the call does not encode the data (sample fragment: `{"key":71733,"title":"Villa Av & Glen Park Ave (Southbound)","stopOrder":190}`).  When I use the DeserializeXmlNode, the ampersand has been Html Endcoded.

To verify that the web service was not encoding the ampersand I used this call to get the json containing the fragment above.

```
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(uri);
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(webClient.DownloadString(uri));
```

and the resulting XML for the json fragment is:

```
<key>71733</key>
<title>Villa Av &amp; Glen Park Ave (Southbound)</title>
```

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: That's **XML** encoding. Disabling it would produce illegal XML, so there is no way to disable it.

Comment: Doh!  You're correct.  I'm pleading temporary loss of mind.